# How to force Photoshop (CC) not to stick to the edges of the image in crop tool mode

Tags: photoshop, cropping

I'm struggling with precise image cropping and rotation when the rotation is less than about 1 degree or if the cropping edge goes too close to the original image boundary. This is frustrating :(

Comment: Thank you so much! Roman Matveev, looking for this for 4 years!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View>Snap

Or Shift+Command+; (on Mac), Shift+Ctrl+; (on PC)